# typename keyword and nested name specifier

Tags: c++, templates, typename, dependent-name

```
struct A{};

template <typename T>
struct B
{
    typename ::A a1; //(1)
    typename A a2; //(2): error
};

int main(){return 0;}
```

Why is the first case correct, but the second isn't? I don't understand the meaning of that restriction.
And anyway, why is the first case allowed? `::A` isn't template-parameter dependent name. What's meaning in it?

Comment: Your example works fine: http://rextester.com/BEF67104. Show the original code

Comment: @user2451677 fails to compile in both g++ and clang++

Comment: I really hope for a really good answer on this question. I am intrigued by this. I am not delusional to think that I know everything in C++ but I think at least I know what I know and what not but there is always someone showing me that I don't know squat.

Comment: I know, that I need to use something else, but not VC++ :). It has always less restrictions

Comment: @user2451677 the word you are searching for is non-conforming :) Although to be fair in the last years significant efforts have been made to bring VC to the C++14 standard.

Comment: @bolov: significant efforts have been made to bring VC to the C++11 standard*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Herb Sutter said that VC aims directly at C++14, implementing C++14 features like generic lambdas before many C++11 features are implemented. My note: They don't have an option for specifying the C++ dialect, so I guess that makes sense for them.

Comment: @bolov: It was a joke, based on VS not even fully supporting C++11 yet (and having quite some way to go). What Sutter says backs that up. It's kinda crazy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did say efforts, but yeah I completely missed your irony. Need to upgrade my antennas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@MikeSeymour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27799165/1782465) explains, going strictly by the standard (C++11, I don't have a C++14 text on hand), case (1) should actually be erroneous as well - `typename` prefixing a qualified name can only be used when there's at least one name on the left-hand side of the `::`.

However, as pointed out by @hvd in the comments, [CWG issue 382](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#382) indicates the actual intent is to allow `typename` before any qualified name, including global-namespace qualification. Since this is what most compilers seem to implement, the rest of this answer follows with this idea.

When viewed like this, it's not that case (2) is a restriction, it's that case (1) is benevolence. The required rule (and its very original wording, I believe) is basically that "if a qualified name which depends on template parameters denotes a type, you must prefix it with `typename`." For convenience, it is loosened to "`typename` can be used for any qualified name which dentoes a type, whether it's dependent or not."<sup>(1)</sup>

In contrast, an unqualified name can never be ambiguous as to whether it refers to a type or not, so it never requires `typename` and `typename` is therefore not allowed there.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>This loosening is not really explicitly stated in the standard, but follows from the combination of several rules. Basically, wherever a *simple-type-specifier* (something which denotes a type) is allowed, the grammar also allows a *typename-specifier* (a qualified name prefixed with `typename`). The rules for templates (mainly in 14.6) only state that `typename` is required when a dependent qualified name denotes a type. Since nothing forbids `typename` in other contexts, it can be used with any qualified name which denotes a type (even outside of template context).

Comment: I'm trying to find the exact wording of the convenience loosening in the standard; I will add it to the answer once I succeed.

Comment: There isn't even any requirement that `typename` only be used inside templates. `struct S { }; typename ::S s;` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @bolov: `::A` isn't ambiguous; but some qualified-ids are, and the grammar just specifies (more or less) that you can use `typename` with any qualified-id, regardless of whether it's necessary to avoid ambiguity. An unqualified-id can't be ambiguous, and the grammar doesn't allow the use of `typename` with one of those.

Comment: Although by my reading of the grammar, `typename ::A` isn't valid. A *typename-specifier* doesn't allow any *qualified-id*, just those involving a *nested-name-specifier*, which involves nesting inside a named type or namespace. `::` alone isn't one of those.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Heck, you're right. Seems the answer's ready for a re-write from the ground up. Or, actually, you should write an answer and I'll just delete mine.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Good point. It has been explicitly stated that the intent is that all qualified names can be preceded by `typename` (CWG issue 382) though, and that is what compilers implement, so this is almost surely an oversight.

Comment: @hvd: Actually, my comment is out of date. C++14 seems to have added `::` as a *nested-name-specifier* (referring to [this draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)).

Answer (score 6):

The rule isn't that you can only use `typename` if the type is nested in a dependent scope. The rules are, more or less:

- you must use `typename` if it's in a dependent scope
- you can only use `typename` where it's allowed by the grammar.

The grammar allows it for a subset of *qualified-id*, specified by

```
typename-specifier:
    typename nested-name-specifier identifier
    typename nested-name-specifier template<opt> simple-template-id

nested-name-specifier:
    :: (C++14 or later)
    ::<opt> type-name ::
    ::<opt> namespace-name ::
    decltype-specifier ::
    nested-name-specifier identifier ::
    nested-name-specifier template<opt> simple-template-id ::
```

So the second case is certainly forbidden, since it doesn't involve any nesting. Strictly speaking, before C++14, the first was also forbidden, since a global qualifier `::` didn't match that grammar.